# Checking two tables against each other in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures

I feel like I'm writing a word problem, but it's really puzzling me and I really hope someone here can solve it:

I want to select one row from table A. Table A includes the attributes Name and Number. But before I finish the query, I want to check it against table B. Table B includes Name, Number, and the Username of the user.
Based on the users' input, it inserts rows into table B that include their Username along with a Name and Number.
Now in my query where I select a row from table A, I want to make sure that there are no rows in table B with matching Name and Number for that particular User.

I have tried WHERE (A.Name = B.Name AND A.Number = B.Number AND B.Username != '$username') but I think I was way off base with that.
Any help would be... amazing.

Comment: != has worked for me in the past, I think both are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.id
from a
where
a.name=:name
and
not exists(select 1 from b where b.id=a.id and b.name=a.name)
```

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful... can you explain the code?

Comment: This simple select a.id
from a
where
a.name=:name

Comment: where tested existing this user in table b: not exists(select 1 from b where b.id=a.id and b.name=a.name)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use exactly this code, but "NOT EXISTS" was the command I was looking for. I didn't know about it, but it really helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   A.id
FROM
   A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON
      (A.Name = B.Name AND A.Number = B.Number)
WHERE
   B.Name IS NULL
   AND B.Number IS NULL
   AND B.Username = ?
```

Comment: This won't quite do it... See, there will be some rows in table B that include the username, but what I'm looking for is rows that don't. There could be like Robert-1-apple and Robert-2-apple and Robert-1-bravo, but what I need is Robert-1-charlie...

Comment: Then also add B.Username IS NULL instead.  I'm not exactly clear on what you want.  Does A also have a username column?  What is the general purpose of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: A doesn't have a username column, just the "name" and "number" to match B. I'm still stumped.

Comment: I need to learn more about joins first... my problem is that I'm already checking against some other factors in the same query... namely where A.value > 10 and such

Comment: The LEFT OUTER JOIN is going to get all rows on A that do not have a matching name/number combo on B (name and number together, that is!).  After that you should be able to work with the values as you please.  Not 100% sure how the username fits in for you, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
  IF NOT EXISTS  ( SELECT 1 
       FROM tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
       ON a.name = b.name
       AND a.number= b.number
       AND b.UserName = 'user' and b.name = 'name'and b.number = 'number')
  SELECT *
  FROM tableA x
  WHERE x.name = 'name'and x.number = 'number'
```